# How to implement restricted choice in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python coding and one of the tasks in my class was to make a quiz on a subject we get to choose, I made the quiz but the lecturer asked if I can restrict the user to chose a,b,c or d, but I can't find a command anywhere that helps with this, and I don't want to sit there and use nested if statements for every letter of the alphabet. any suggestions that I can use to implement restricted choice in a quiz?

Comment: You don't need nested `if` statements for this, normal `if` statements are enough.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
q_text = """
What is your favorite metasyntactic variable? 
A) foo B) bar
C) baz D) foobar
"""

while(input(q_text).upper() not in ('A', 'B', 'C','D')):
    print("please enter A, B, C or D")
```

you can test if an item (in this case the input of the user) is in a sequence by using the `in` keyword (and negate it with `not`)